# Call indicator bar is not responding for audio and video call

Tags: xcode, twilio, twilio-api, callkit, twilio-click-to-call

I have implemented Twilio voice kit successfully in the application.

I am not able to move in the application from call indicator. Also, I am not able to see green bar on other application screen when user moves from call screen. I have added custom view in navigation bar, but it's not much responsive.

[image: Call indicator from where user is not able to enter in the application.]

[image: Custom call status indicator in navigation bar.]

I have following doubts for the same.

- Is there any default property which I need to enable to display
  native call indicator in the application?
- Do I need to put a custom
  view as I have done? If yes then what will be the best approach to do
  it?
- Is there any alternative to display custom call indicator inside
  the application rather than adding view in navigation bar?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `CallKit` framework does not have any API for you to use to display their native UI regarding the calls. The green indicator bar is shown if you have an active VoIP call and your app is running in background.

By tapping on it it will just open your VoIP app.

The best approach is to use a custom-built `UIView`, placed on a separate `UIWindow` that has the same level as the system's status bar and add a tap gesture on it to achieve what the native green bar is doing. Also, you can even add the animation that fades in and out a label to create the same experience as the native green bar.

Comment: I have created custom view and added it into the application as given in below link. But it's not much responsive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470562/how-do-i-detect-touches-on-uistatusbar-iphone I am not able to detect clicks on statusbar.