# Add customview in navigation bar like whatsapp

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, custom-view, uistatusbar

I want to create custom navigation bar like WhatsApp uses to display call indicator in the application as given below.

[image]

I have successfully added view like above but it's not responsive because I am not able to detect touch on status bar. I can touch only part below "Touch to return to call".

Code is as given below.

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *navigationBarTopView;

UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (_navigationBarTopView == nil) {
    _navigationBarTopView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, 60.0)];
        [_navigationBarTopView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76.0/255.0 green:217.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _navigationBarTopView.frame.size.height - 15, window.frame.size.width, 10)];
    [label setText:@"Touch to return to call"];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [_navigationBarTopView addSubview:label];

    //The setup code (in viewDidLoad in your view controller)
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [_navigationBarTopView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap1];
}

[window addSubview:_navigationBarTopView];
```

I have also tried to add touch on status bar as give below but it doesn't work.

[How do I detect touches on UIStatusBar/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470562/how-do-i-detect-touches-on-uistatusbar-iphone)

Also navigation bar is not coming downside. I have tried to set `keyWindow` frame. But that is also not working.

Comment: Are you sure this is not system `call bar`?

Comment: try this `[self.navigationController.view addSubview: _navigationBarTopView];`

Comment: It is a system generated navigation bar. It appears automatically while connected a call with anyone. The call can be normal or VoIP(Manage by SDK). You can add a custom view to the navigation bar if required.

Comment: its the default behaviour provided by apple, if you want to create the same like  add subview to  navigationController.view on your top viewcontroller

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani I am not getting it into the application. I have implemented Twilio Voice SDK for the same. So I have created custom view and added it as a  UIWindow on top of the screen.

Comment: @ManWithBear Yes this is not a system call bar, I have added a custom view.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Even I want default one but not sure why it's not appearing.

Comment: Twilio voice SDK do not have this type of feature. I am sure about voice call but no idea with a video call. You can go with a @Anbu.Karthik solution but it is very tricky and difficult to manage for all device. By using below solution you cannot achieve output like WhatsApp so be careful and happy coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIStatusBar has higher priority than your application's window, so you won't get any touch event through status bar.

To get touch event through status bar you need a window with higher window level than UIStatusBar.

Try below code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic) UIWindow *buttonWindow;
@property (nonatomic) UIWindow *textWindow;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat callViewHeight;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        if (([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].safeAreaInsets.top > 20.0)) {
            self.callViewHeight = 55.0f;
        } else {
            self.callViewHeight = 35.0f;
        }
    } else {
        self.callViewHeight = 35.0f;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)showVideoCallButton{
    self.textWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.callViewHeight)];
    self.textWindow.windowLevel = self.window.windowLevel + 1;
    self.textWindow.hidden = FALSE;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.callViewHeight)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:76.0/255.0 green:217.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    view.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
    UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.callViewHeight)];
    lblName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lblName setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]];
    lblName.text = @"";

    UILabel *lblTouch = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.callViewHeight - 20.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20.0f)];
    lblTouch.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lblTouch setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]];
    lblTouch.text = @"Touch to return to call";
    lblTouch.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

    [view addSubview:lblTouch];
    [view addSubview:lblName];

    [self.textWindow addSubview:view];

    self.buttonWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.callViewHeight)];
    self.buttonWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    self.buttonWindow.hidden = FALSE;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:lblName.bounds];
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.buttonWindow addSubview:button];

    self.textWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.callViewHeight);
    self.buttonWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.callViewHeight);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.textWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         self.buttonWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
                             if (([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].safeAreaInsets.top > 20.0)) {
                                 self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.callViewHeight - 40.0f, self.window.bounds.size.width, self.window.bounds.size.height - self.callViewHeight + 40.0f);
                             } else {
                                 self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.callViewHeight - 20.0f, self.window.bounds.size.width, self.window.bounds.size.height - self.callViewHeight + 20.0f);
                             }
                         } else {
                             self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.callViewHeight - 20.0f, self.window.bounds.size.width, self.window.bounds.size.height - self.callViewHeight + 20.0f);
                         }
                     }];
}

-(void)hideVideoCallButton{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.textWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.callViewHeight);
                         self.buttonWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.callViewHeight);
                         self.window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                             self.buttonWindow.hidden = TRUE;
                             self.buttonWindow = nil;

                             self.textWindow.hidden = TRUE;
                             self.textWindow = nil;
                         });

                     }];
}

-(void)buttonTouched{
    NSLog(@"Button Touched");
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks @iDhaval this solution worked. I have made some changes to make it compatible with iPhone X+ devices.

Comment: hello, is there any solution for swift?

Comment: @iDhaval, i tried it and it doesnt work in xcode 11.6

Comment: @swift2geek what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried in singleViewcontroller and UITabbar Controller also, the sample project I attached [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8wgsf6), for status bar Tap action I followed [Flar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
     [self createDummyView];
});


}

 -(void)createDummyView{

if (_navigationBarTopView == nil) {
     float statusBarHeight = [self statusBarHeight];
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    _navigationBarTopView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height +  statusBarHeight)];
    [_navigationBarTopView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76.0/255.0 green:217.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _navigationBarTopView.frame.size.height - 15,width, 10)];
    [label setText:@"Touch to return to call"];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote]];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_navigationBarTopView addSubview:label];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [_navigationBarTopView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_navigationBarTopView];


}


-(float) statusBarHeight
{
CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
return MIN(statusBarSize.width, statusBarSize.height);
}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
NSLog(@"recognizer == %@", recognizer.view.tag);
}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: The device with safe-area available calling functionality does not work like non-safe-area device. It will display a small calling icon in the status bar

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have already implemented this code but using that code I am not able to get touch on status bar. Also I have complex structure which consist a tabbar and which consist 4 navigation bar controllers. So It's very difficult to manage in the application.

Comment: To have touch event on status bar I am using this solution. But it doesn't work on tab bar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470562/how-do-i-detect-touches-on-uistatusbar-iphone It works well with single view controller.

Comment: Please use this library for the same. I know, maybe some customization required but it will easy to use and ratings are good.  https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit

Comment: @JayeshSojitra - I updated the answer , it works fine for single view controller and UITabbar controller also, please check

Comment: @JayeshSojitra - I have complex structure which consist a tabbar and which consist 4 navigation bar controllers. So It's very difficult to manage in the application : use extension ,

Comment: @HiteshSurani this is different. Your lib is more like notifications, but the question here is about more like a system bar, which moves down from the top and pushes all content below.